# Getting API Result with closure and passing it into an other ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, api, closures

I'm getting an API Result in my viewModel as below:

```
class HomePageViewModel {

var apiResult: CountryDataFromAPI?

//Getting API result via viewModel

public func getAPIResult(withOffset: Int, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    APIHandler.urlRequest(with: withOffset) { result in
        self.apiResult?.data.append(contentsOf: result.data)
        print("api resultdata in viewmodel is \(result.data)")
        completion()
    }
 }
}
```

Getting the api works fine. In the code above, I can print the statement as *print("api resultdata in viewmodel is (result.data)")* and see the expected api result.

When I get the data inside my viewModel as above, I use it in my mainViewController.

My mainViewController is initialized with the ViewModel

```
class HomePageViewController: UIViewController {

private var viewModel : HomePageViewModel
private var countryDataArray: [CountryData]?

init(with viewModel: HomePageViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
 }
}
```

Everything works fine until I try to get the data from viewModel as below.
I'm trying to set the data in ViewModel to a parameter called countryDataArray. But while doing that inside the closure, my print statement "*print("data in vc is (self?.viewModel.apiResult?.data)")*" prints out nil even though it gets the data in viewModel.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Getting API Result in viewDidLoad. And after getting the result, reloading the tableView.
    self.viewModel.getAPIResult(withOffset: 11) { [weak self] in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
            self?.countryDataArray = self?.viewModel.apiResult?.data
            print("data in vc is \(self?.viewModel.apiResult?.data)")
            self?.countriesListTableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

Why this might be happening?

PS: My api models are as below:

```
struct CountryDataFromAPI: Codable {
var data: [CountryData]
}

struct CountryData: Codable,Equatable {
let name : String
let code: String
let wikiDataId: String    
}
```

Comment: Have you used the debugger to determine which part of `self?.viewModel.apiResult?.data` is actually nil? It might be `self` or `apiResult`.

Comment: apiResult looks like nil, but it has data inside viewModel. Since I'm initializing viewController with that ViewModel, I'm expecting it to have the data inside viewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the problem is the `self.apiResult?.data.append(contentsOf: result.data)`

You didn't assign any value for the apiResult.data. Because apiResult is nil.

You have to initialize the apiResult after you get data back from API.

Comment: I agree with this but would also argue that there is no point in storing the whole result from the API call if it is only `data` that is used. So maybe change it to `var apiResult: [CountryData]`. Then this property and the same view controller property can be made non-optional and initialised as empty arrays.

Comment: You both are totally right. When I initialized the apiResult as var apiResult: [CountryData] = [] it worked. Could you please tell me why this is the issue and why it is not working with optionals? After appending a data to optional array, am I not initializing it with data?